# Advantage of using one over the other mentioned in the code below or the difference between the two lines?

Tags: c#

i am new to C# and i would like to know what is the advantage of using the second line of code instead of the first or the difference between the both,
i'm just trying to understand some code changes in the migration please explain to me in detail, thanks in advance.

1. `Execute(string procedureName, IDictionary<string, IConvertible> parameters = null)`
2. `Execute<T>(string procedureName, T parameters = null) where T:class,new()`

Comment: The answer cannot be given without knowing more about the context. Please add more information.

Comment: Presumably the second method is there to allow a call of the form `Execute("myProc", new { Param1 = ... , Param2 = .. })` using anonymous types, which is more convenient to the caller than having to construct and pass a dictionary (but harder/slower to use for the callee, as reflection is needed to get at the values). This is a fairly common pattern in object relational mapping libraries.

Comment: thank you so much for your comment, i can get a clear idea of why it has been done, i'll do a bit more research into it. @JeroenMostert